# Node js | MySql Insertion "Killed"

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, csv

I wrote the following *Node.js* Code for inserting millions of records into *MySQL*.

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var fs         = require('fs');
var csv        = require('fast-csv');

var connection = mysql.createPool({
    user: 'root',
    password: '***********',
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3306,
    database: '***********'
});
```

Below,I am pooling the connection

```
var getConnection = function(callback) {
connection.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
   callback(err, connection);
 });
};
var i = 1;

csv
.fromPath("company.csv")
.on("data", function(data){
    data.forEach(function(item){
    getConnection(function(err, conn){

     conn.query('INSERT INTO postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (1,"' + i +'","'+ item +'")', function(err, rows) {
       if(err){
       console.log(err);
       }
   });
 });
});
i = i + 1;
})
 .on("end", function(){
  console.log("done");
  console.log(i);
});
```

Although everything gets executed properly, nothing is inserted into the database!

What is wrong with the code ?
Any other solution for inserting huge amount of data into *MySQL* through *Node.js* ?

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: Pretty sure there's something wrong with your `conn.query`. Your string never ends. But I don't know node.js, though.

Comment: @Keker I believe that's merely because they're pasting from nano, judging by the `$` at the end of that line, which indicates the line spans past the width of the terminal.

Comment: One issue is that you're not releasing the connection after your query is done. If you do not do this, no connections will be left in the pool. This means once you've ran n queries (where n is the connection pool size), all other queries will get queued up, but never executed.

Comment: Ok. its just testing code...
But insertion also not done !

Comment: At some point you'll want to look at using something like [Sequelize](http://sequelizejs.com) rather than banging around with the low-level MySQL driver.